Error while upgrading Angular from version 10 to 17: Namespace has no exported member
I'm currently in the process of upgrading an Angular application from version 10 to version 17. While converting from Angular 10 to Angular 11.2.9, I encountered the following error messages:
Error: node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/lib/data/country-code.d.ts:4:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/RakshithK/Documents/Projects/NomaErp/tempFiles/triel_and _error/f2/Noma-erp-fe-v2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

11     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<NgxIntlTelInputModule, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/lib/ngx-intl-tel-input.module.d.ts:12:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/RakshithK/Documents/Projects/NomaErp/tempFiles/triel_and _error/f2/Noma-erp-fe-v2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

12     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<NgxIntlTelInputModule, [typeof i1.NgxIntlTelInputComponent, typeof i2.NativeElementInjectorDirective], [typeof i3.CommonModule, typeof i4.FormsModule, typeof i4.ReactiveFormsModule, typeof i5.BsDropdownModule], [typeof i1.NgxIntlTelInputComponent, typeof i2.NativeElementInjectorDirective]>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/lib/ngx-intl-tel-input.module.d.ts:12:262 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'i1'.

12     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<NgxIntlTelInputModule, [typeof i1.NgxIntlTelInputComponent, typeof i2.NativeElementInjectorDirective], [typeof i3.CommonModule, typeof i4.FormsModule, typeof i4.ReactiveFormsModule, typeof i5.BsDropdownModule], [typeof i1.NgxIntlTelInputComponent, typeof i2.NativeElementInjectorDirective]>;
   
Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1032:27-49
Can't import the named export 'BsDropdownDirective' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1032:90-116
Can't import the named export 'BsDropdownMenuDirective' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1124:30-46
Can't import the named export 'BsDropdownModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1140:60-79
Can't import the named export 'BsDropdownModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1032:51-79
Can't import the named export 'BsDropdownToggleDirective' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)


Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1159:16-28
Can't import the named export 'CommonModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1041:10-19
Can't import the named export 'Component' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1032:118-141
Can't import the named export 'DefaultValueAccessor' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 534:10-19
Can't import the named export 'Directive' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 544:12-25
Can't import the named export 'ElementRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

[91mError: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 565:29-41
Can't import the named export 'EventEmitter' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)



Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1159:30-41
Can't import the named export 'FormsModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 419:10-20
Can't import the named export 'Injectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)


Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1113:12-17
Can't import the named export 'Input' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)



Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1050:17-30
Can't import the named export 'NG_VALIDATORS' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 983:13-30
Can't import the named export 'NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1032:15-25
Can't import the named export 'NgClass' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)


Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 542:12-24
Can't import the named export 'NgControl' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1032:143-161
Can't import the named export 'NgControlStatus' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1032:207-217
Can't import the named export 'NgForOf' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1032:81-88
Can't import the named export 'NgIf' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1032:163-173
Can't import the named export 'NgModel' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1116:12-18
Can't import the named export 'Output' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)


Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1159:43-62
Can't import the named export 'ReactiveFormsModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1119:12-21
Can't import the named export 'ViewChild' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 985:17-27
Can't import the named export 'forwardRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)


Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 588:4-12
Can't import the named export 'setTheme' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 405:10-28
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 991:7-30
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵNgOnChangesFeature' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 20:4-16
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵadvance' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 76:4-16
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵadvance' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1029:6-20
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵattribute' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 948:32-52
[91mCan't import the named export 'ɵɵdefineComponent' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 524:38-58
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵdefineDirective' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 61:4-16
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelement' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 84:4-16
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelement' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 99:4-16
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelement' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1000:6-18
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelement' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1002:6-18
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelement' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 16:4-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 40:4-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 41:4-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 62:4-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 65:4-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 68:4-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 69:4-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 100:4-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 103:4-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 106:4-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 107:4-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 128:4-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 129:4-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1003:6-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1005:6-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1016:6-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1017:6-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementEnd' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 14:4-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 27:4-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 28:4-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 52:4-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 60:4-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 63:4-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 66:4-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

0mError: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 90:4-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 98:4-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 101:4-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 104:4-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 122:4-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 124:4-21
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 997:6-23
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 998:6-23
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 999:6-23
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1006:6-23
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵelementStart' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 26:16-35
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵgetCurrentView' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 51:17-36
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵgetCurrentView' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 89:17-36
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵgetCurrentView' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 29:4-17
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵlistener' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 53:4-17
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵlistener' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 91:4-17
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵlistener' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1007:6-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵlistener' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 957:29-43
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵloadQuery' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 19:19-35
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵnextContext' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 31:21-37
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵnextContext' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 35:22-38
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵnextContext' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 44:19-35
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵnextContext' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)


Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 413:0-27
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)


Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 399:19-40
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 407:20-44
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjectable' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1134:29-51
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 46:4-17
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵproperty' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1022:31-49
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵpureFunction1' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 957:6-23
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵqueryRefresh' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 57:18-32
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵreference' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 95:18-32
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵreference' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 30:6-22
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵrestoreView' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 34:6-22
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵrestoreView' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 54:6-22
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵrestoreView' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 92:6-22
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵrestoreView' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 123:4-17
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtemplate' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 125:4-17
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtemplate' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 126:4-17
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtemplate' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 127:4-17
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtemplate' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1001:6-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtemplate' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 1004:6-19
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtemplate' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 15:4-13
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtext' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 64:4-13
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtext' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 67:4-13
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtext' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 102:4-13
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtext' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 105:4-13
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtext' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 77:4-24
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtextInterpolate' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 115:4-24
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtextInterpolate' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 21:4-25
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtextInterpolate1' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 79:4-25
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtextInterpolate1' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 117:4-25
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵtextInterpolate1' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Error: ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/fesm2015/ngx-intl-tel-input.mjs 953:6-20
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵviewQuery' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

I've searched for solutions but haven't found a clear resolution yet.
my present package.json file is as bellow:
{
  "name": "noma-erp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "api": "json-server api/api.js --routes api/routes.json --no-cors=true"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^11.1.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^11.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "css-vars-ponyfill": "^2.3.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.6",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.12",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "json-server": "^0.17.4",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.0",
    "mix-scss": "^1.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^10.0.0-alpha.11",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^2.1.2",
    "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^3.2.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^12.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.9",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^11.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.35",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.11",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}

Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Could you try reducing the typescript version from "~4.1.5" to "~4.0.2"
Github Issue Reference

Always better to include what you can from referenced material rather than just a link...

Actually, I want to upgrade it to the latest Angular version, so when I update to Angular 17, it should use anyway the latest TypeScript version, right?

@rakshith you have to do it step by step, use ng update and angular update guide to upgrade to the proper versions, angular does not always use the latest versions of typescript since the latest will always keep changing
